# How do I merge multiple edges together?

Tags: edges

I am looking to merge the two edges to the right with the edge to the left, more specifically I want to snap the two right edges onto the position where the left edge is and then merge them together so all the faces connected to the left edge get connected to the right one's.

I've tried Bridge Edge loops but it didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Create a vertex on the left edge (you can subdivide this edge for example), enable the *Auto Merge* option and the *Snap to Vertex*, select the vertex on the right and move it until it snaps to the left vertex:

[image]

Comment: This worked and also let me merge the vertices together which gave me just the amount of edges I wanted. Thanks.